# translation based on quote language in conga templates salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a requirement to translate quote templates built-in conga to 18 languages based on the language field mentioned on the quote. As I understand the custom labels and the translation workbench works based on users. Is there any way to do this? creating custom metadata for each language.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution which allow to translate fields labels and products name in order to manage quote templates in multilanguage.

- For the fields labels, you can create for each field you want in the template a new formula field with the translated label and use those fields in the template related to the language
- For the products name, you can create a text field in the product object like "Product French Name" and you put in this field the translation
  => Then in the Quote Line Item you can create a formula field like "Produit" (in French here) and in the formula you have just to retrieve the value of the field created in the product object and to put in the template.
  Don't know if it help you bu if the standard Salesforce is used, it works perfectly.